# Why can't I view this image?

Tags: windows-xp, images, rename

I downloaded an image (JPEG) and gave it a long name for it. Once it was downloaded, I was able to give it a long name. Today, when I renamed the folder where I had saved that jpeg file, the image turned to some useless file *all of a sudden*...

I downloaded a fresh copy of the same file and renamed it again with the same *long name*. Looks like it can stay with the file without being over-written. Right-clicking on the damaged file shows no useful options. Dragging it to Paint or Photoshop or to desktop didn't have an effect. Pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> sounds with "Ding". The damaged one is near the new file:

[image]

Using a root browser like WinRAR, I thought of editing the file. It shows something like:

> *Renaming* - Access denied - CRC failure (File does not exist)
>
> *Pressing delete key shows* - You cannot delete this file

I've heard something like *"XP (I think NTFS) allows only 64 chars for file names"* and I'm totally satisfied with that. If it does, then it shouldn't have allowed me to rename the file the first time. Resting for these many days and showing up when the folder was modified seems ridiculous to me. Does this happen often (when we use long file names) in XP?

If it does, is there a way to recover it? (I don't think there's a way, because I've tried many) It's not a problem for this file. But, it happened to 2 or 3 files in that folder.

Comment: What exactly did you try already?  Did you do a disk check to ensure you don't have and disk/file system corruption? (`chkdsk`).  FYI: [The long filename system allows a maximum length of 255 UTF-16 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename)

Comment: @techie007: It worked. `chkdsk` finally said that it has fixed some errors. I found the image inside the drive with its original name. Thanks Techie ;-)

Comment: I'll throw it in as an actual answer then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the suddenness of the change, and the fact it's happened with more than one file in that folder, I'd suggest running a disk check (`chkdsk <drive letter>`) to find/correct any potential file system and/or disk corruption.